# Entering another Schengen country with a Fiktionsbescheinigung without entering germany first

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, germany, visa-extensions, hungary

I have gotten a Fiktionsbescheinigung with third box ticked. I’ll be travelling from germany but for the return I’m planning to go to hungary. So my question is would the immigration officer in hungary allow it or will I have to enter germany first and then go to hungary. Has someone done something like that and did it work? I want to travel to lebanon then hungary and then back to germany.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this should be no problem since it an extension of an existing residence permit.

The Schengen Border Code only prohibits first time applications (first box of Fiktionsbescheinigung).

> Schengen Border Code
> Article 2
> Definitions
> 16. ‘residence permit’ means:
> ...
> (b) ...**with the exception of**:
>
> > (i) **temporary permits issued pending examination of a first application for a residence permit** as referred to in point (a) or an application for asylum; and
>
> ...

---

The third box ticked refers to:

> [§81 (4) - Act on the Residence, AufentG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1732)
> If a foreigner applies for an extension of his or her residence title or for a different residence title before his or her current residence title expires, **the current residence title is deemed to remain in force from the time it expires until the time of the decision by the foreigners authority**.
> ...

The **Prado** (Public Register of Authentic travel and identity Documents) database contains information about these documents, so that other countries can look it up if they are not familar an individuell document.

- [Council of the European Union - PRADO - DEU-HO-12001](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/DEU-HO-12001/index.html)

Comment: The Schengen Borders Code says nothing about first applications or any other application.

Comment: @phoog It certainly does in Schengen Border Code Article 2 (16)(b)(i).